# Android: Difference Between Google Maps & Google places?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

can please sombody tell me what is difference?

one is free and other is commercal.

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/?hl=en#sup_1

So I want these feature: (is it google map or google place?)

1- show my current location

2- import data (markers) form json.

3- click on info windows for each marker.

4- draw path between 2 marker.

Comment: Looks like maps is enough for you.

Comment: I think 'current place' is for place API...don't you think?

Comment: Nope - you need no libraries to get your current location, it is framework-provided. Then you just have to add a marker on the map at that position.

Comment: all you need for the features is google maps v2

Comment: roughly answered here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Google-Maps-API-and-Google-Places-API